# Install cron tasks in a docker run command

Tags: nginx, docker, alpine-linux

I have created a base image of alpine/nginx/php-fpm that I use to deploy several websites.

Each site has it's own cron jobs.

How can I create custom cron jobs to start in the docker run command when the container is initialised?

Comment: Well you obviously have a process manager of some sort in there...  Add cron.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thinking about microservices architecture as well as docker philosophy to run one service per container, I rather use dockerhost's `cron` to schedule container's tasks instead of installing `cron` in each container.

In order to do that, name your containers properly then start using:

```
docker exec <container name> /path/to/shell /path/to/script
```

Test the above command, and if if works as expected, schedule it using `cron` on the dockerhost.

Comment: To execute a PHP script, would it not also need the path the PHP binary?

Would something like this work?

`docker exec <container name> bash /usr/bin/php /var/www/test.php >> /var/log/cron.log 2>&1`

Comment: Thats Correct. If you dont need logging you can even omit bash.

Comment: This way I've to modify host machine manually, how can I automatize that?